# Cartesian product with all elements

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, combinations

I have two sets A and B with

$A = \{1,2,3\} \\
B = \{ A, B, C, D, E \}$

Now I need to get something similar to the Cartesian product. If my understanding is correct, the Cartesian product would return several sets with only 2 elements in each of them.
I need the combinations of all elements:

$1A\\
...\\
1ABCDE\\
..\\
123A\\
...\\
123ABCDE$

The order doesn't matter; each new set should contain each element only once. So no $11A$.

Is there a suitable operation?

Comment: The order *does* matter. I find it useful to think of the Cartesian product of sets $A$ and $B$ as follows:  $\forall x,y:[(x,y)\in A\times B \iff x\in A\land y\in B]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the set of subsets of elements from both $A$ and $B$ that contain at least one element of $A$ and one element of $B$. If that is what you want, then you want

$$[\mathcal P(A\cup B)\setminus\mathcal P(A)]\setminus\mathcal P(B)$$

or

$$\mathcal P(A\cup B)\cap\mathcal P(A)^c\cap\mathcal P(B)^c$$

where $\mathcal P(X)$ is the power set of $X$, i.e. the set of all subsets of $X$, "$\setminus$" is the setminus operator, i.e. $X\setminus Y=X\cap Y^c$ is the set of all elements in $X$ that are not in $Y$, and "$^c$" is the complement operator.

I have never seen separate notation for what you want, but combining the powerset and setminus operators is pretty easy. My first expression would look a little simpler if you remove the brackets but I wanted to make my order of operations explicit. I think the order is more clear in the second expression, though the complement operator may be more iffy in the general theory of sets in ZF theory. (It is perfectly fine in NBG, with which I am more familiar.)

Comment: You may also write $\mathcal P (A \cup B) \setminus ( \mathcal P (A) \cup \mathcal P (B))$ for this to avoid both complements and "asymmetry".

Comment: @Stefan: Good point!

Comment: @Stefan: Where is the difference between $P(A∪B)$ and $P(A)∪P(B)$?

Comment: @user1170330: $\mathcal P(A\cup B)$ contains all sets that have elements from $A$ or $B$ or both. $\mathcal P(A)\cup\mathcal P(B)$ contains all sets that only have elements from $A$ or only elements from $B$ *but not from both*. In your example $\{1,E\}\in\mathcal P(A\cup B)$ but $\{1,E\}\not\in\mathcal P(A)\cup\mathcal P(B)$. That difference is critical to my answer.