# Powerset with constraints

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, combinations, constraints

I have two sets $NUMBERS$ and $LETTERS$ with:

$ NUMBERS = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} \\
LETTERS = \{ A, B, C, D, E\}$

No I want the power-set of my sets, i.e. the set of subsets of elements from both $NUMBERS$ and $LETTERS$ that contain at least one element of $NUMBERS$ and one element of $LETTERS$.
But with two constraints:

1. If the new set contains either $1$ or $2$, it also has to contain $2$ or $1$.
   Short: $1$ and $2$ **may occur together only**.

Not allowed:

- $1CB$ (1, but no 2)
- $23B$ (2, but no 1)

Allowed:

- $12CB$ (1 together with 2)
- $21A$ (2 together with 1)
- $3C$ (no 1 or 2 at all)

  2. `A` and `B` are **not allowed** to occur together.

Not allowed:

- $3AB$ (A and B together)
- $23BCA$ (B and A together)

Allowed:

- $12CB$ (Only B, but no A)
- $21A$ (Only A, but no B)
- $345D$ (Neither A, nor B)

I learned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345806/cartesian-product-with-all-elements/1345841), that the formula for the power sets in my case is:
$P(NUMBERS ∪LETTERS )\setminus(P(NUMBERS )∪P(LETTERS ))$, but I'm not sure, how to define my constraints.

How can I change my formula to meet my constraints?

Comment: Do you want a formula for your new constrained set or for the size of the set? (I ask since you have the tag "combinatorics" which counts sets rather than defines them.)

Comment: @RoryDaulton: I would like to have a new adjusted formula.

Answer (score 0):

CORRECTION:  my original answer double counted some cases.  I believe this version fixes that error.

In the set NUMBERS, treat the elements {1,2} as a single element X.  Thus the set NUMBERS is replaced with NUMBERS* = {X, 3, 4, 5}.  That ensures that your first constraint is always satisfied.  To handle the second, first look at $LETTERS_1$= {A, C, D, E}.  Forming sets between these, and using at least one element from each, just means picking a non empty subset of each.  Thus there are $(2^4 -1)^2$ ways to do it. The same observations pertain to $LETTERS_2$ = {B, C, D, E}.  Adding these double counts the cases where neither A nor B occurs, hence we must subtract eligible sets formed between NUMBERS* and {3,4,5}.  There are $(2^4 -1)^2 (2^3 - 1)$ of these.  Hence the total is $2 (2^4 -1)^2 - (2^4 -1)(2^3-1) $ which works out to 550 - 105 = 345.

Comment: nope wrong is this answer yet

Comment: Are you sure?  As I say in my comment to your solution, I think you are not using constraint #2 correctly.