# Set of subsets of elements of $n$ sets that contain at least one element of each set

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

In short, I am interested in a generalization of the considerations in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345806/cartesian-product-with-all-elements) from $2$ to $n$ sets.

The case of $2$ sets: Consider two sets $A$ and $B$ with a possibly different number of elements. I am looking to find the set of all subsets of elements of $A$ and $B$ that contain at least one element of $A$ and one element of $B$. Let $\mathcal P(x)$ denote the power set operator that returns the set of all subsets of $x$ and $\setminus$ is the setminus operator. Then the solution set to this problem may be written as

$$[\mathcal P(A\cup B)\setminus\mathcal P(A)]\setminus\mathcal P(B)$$

or

$$\mathcal P(A \cup B) \setminus ( \mathcal P(A) \cup \mathcal P(B))$$

as elaborated in the question I've linked above. I am wondering whether there is an extension to an arbitrary number of sets.

Consider three sets $A$, $B$, and $C$. I have tried to extend the result above to

$$\mathcal P(A \cup B \cup C) \setminus ( \mathcal P(A) \cup \mathcal P(B) \cup \mathcal P(C)).$$

However, when programming this, the result contains e.g. some terms that do not contain any element of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both here and in the earlier question there appears to be an unstated assumption that the sets in question are pairwise disjoint; if not, a subset of $A$ could in fact contain an element of $B$ and so meet the requirement of containing elements of both $A$ and $B$.

It’s not enough to throw out the subsets of $A$, $B$, and $C$: as you’ve discovered, that still leaves you with sets that contain elements of just two of the three sets. What you want is (for three sets)

$$\wp(A\cup B\cup C)\setminus\big(\wp(A\cup B)\cup\wp(A\cup C)\cup\wp(B\cup C)\big):$$

this throws out every subset of $A\cup B\cup C$ that is actually a subset of some pair of the sets $A$, $B$, and $C$. Throwing out $\wp(A\cup B)$, for instance, excludes all subsets of $A\cup B\cup C$ that contain no element of $C$.

More generally, if you have sets $A_1,\ldots,A_n$, you want

$$\wp\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k\right)\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^n\wp\left(\bigcup_{\substack{1\le i\le n\\i\ne k}}A_i\right)\;,$$

throwing out everything that is a subset of the union of some $n-1$ of the $n$ sets.